# How can I convert a numerical value to text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I would like to convert a numerical value to a text string. I am opening several windows with the `window.open()` command and I would like these windows not to be on top of each other.

For that I use the argument "left" and "top" in the windows.open command but these parameters need to be text entities.

```
for (var i = 0; i < final_number; ++i )
{
    left_value=50+(50*i);
    list[i]=window.open(url[i],"","height=500,left=left_value,width=1000");
};
```

When calculating `left_value=50+(50*i)`, the result is numerical.

The problem is that the `window.open()` command is expecting a text parameter for `left_value`.

I thus want to convert left_value from `X` to `"X"`

Answer (score 5):

You can construct a string using the plus operator:

```
for (var i = 0; i < final_number; ++i ) { 
   left_value=50+(50*i); 
   list[i]=window.open(url[i],"", "height=500,left="+left_value+",width=1000"); 
};
```

Also, I would suggest using a tool like the firefox plugin firebug to help debug your javascript.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
I do have firebug. I don't quite know how to use it for JS debugging though. Any recommendation to get me started?

Comment: yea, if you activate and click on the console tab there should be an area on the right where you can actually enter javascript and run it. Recommended reading: http://getfirebug.com/docs.html

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation:

```
'height=500,width=1000,left=' + left_value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following string conversion to convert number to string

```
var intValue=4;
intValue= ''+intValue;
```

in first statment intValue is of type long and then it will be converted to string.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple conversion to a string you can use:

```
strvalue = String(value)
```

But usually explicit conversions like this are not needed since javascript does automatic type conversions when appropriate.